# Mongoose Schema use of 'new' when introducing it as PART of an exported module

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, import

ok so given i got the following code accompanying a userSchema while using Mongoose and we try to export it as follows:

```
module.exports  = {
    model:mongoose.model('User',userSchema),
    getById:function(id,callback){
        model.findById(id,callback);
    },
    getByUsername:function(username,callback){
        model.findOne({username:username},callback);
    }
}
```

and i would like to import this like so ....

```
const user = require('../models/user');
...
let newUser = new user.model({
        name:req.body.name,
        email:req.body.email,
        pasword:req.body.password,
        username:req.body.username
    });
```

and it's not working primarily because user.model it's returning undefined...now i *know* i could do something like the following and it *works*

```
module.exports = model:mongoose.model('User',userSchema);

module.exports.myMethods { 
    getById:function(id,callback){
        model.findById(id,callback);
    },
    getByUsername:function(username,callback){
        model.findOne({username:username},callback);
    }
}
```

and all is fine when importing as follows....

```
const user = require('../models/user');
...
let newUser = new user({
        name:req.body.name,
        email:req.body.email,
        pasword:req.body.password,
        username:req.body.username
    });
```

Question is how do you make the first approach work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first approach should work. are you sure it was user.model being undefined?

You can also try something like this:

```
let user = {};

user.model = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

user.getById = function(id,callback){
    model.findById(id,callback);
}

user.getByUsername = function(username,callback){
   model.findOne({username:username},callback);
}

module.exports = user;
```

Comment: the issue was not my code but indeed it was nodemon! It seems not to be updating the server-side code and is going in a loop :( And yes confirmed mine works yours works also of course and the second method i mentioned is also working BUT is not recommendable for obvious reasons. Am marking your answer as correct.